# Amarok won’t uninstall and gives error 1

Tags: software-uninstall

Amarok-utils and have tried almost everything on boards and no results.  In terminal tried autoclean dpkg and no results

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please mention your OS, its version and the exact commands you've tried and what the resulting terminal output is.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu’ 18.04  I am total noob https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/br2p07/need_help_installing_ararok/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ios_share_flow_optimization&utm_term=control_2  an error occurred, please run package manager  error: broken count> 0  I’ve tried almost every sudo apt variation  and it yields the same results of amarok unmet dependencies and try —fix or it all is the same results.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include *exact* command and *exact* output from the command.

Comment: sudo apt -f install and the following other comands that tried to kill package or clear the amarok and still have that error unmet package dependencies

Comment: gksu software-properties-gtk after I check all and revert it goes back to need internet connection yet I am on the connection and same results

Comment: I figured it out through settings and deleting the Amarok through and through